# AS2 was not signed is received in MDN

Tags: actionscript-2, bouncycastle

I am new to AS2 and s/mime protocols. We have a requirement to send AS2 message to our trading partner. I researched multiple sites and able to send AS2 message. I used encrypt and signature for sending the AS2 using Bouncy Castle provider. In the MDN message the trading partner mentions that the AS2 was not signed. I am not clear whats going. It would really be very helpful if you can provide any suggestions hints.

Comment: I was able to get rid of AS2 was not signed but now i get a message that "Unable to verify the signature". I tried to verify it locally and i get a message that "message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value".

However, when i tried with content encapsulated during signature, the content is successfully verified. But as per AS2, i will have to send the detached signature in the application/pkcs7-signature body part.

Can you any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to solve the issue. When i used SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator and SMIMESignedGenerator i was able to successfully send the data as requried to the partner AS2.